# Laravel Вывод списка маршрутов с методом GET и определенным префиксом

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.6
PHP 7.2

Получаю массив маршрутов следующим образом:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RouteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

        return dd($routeCollection);

    }
}
```

Собственно список маршрутов могу получить методом

```
foreach($routeCollection as $route)
{
   echo $route->uri();
}
```

Теперь вопрос, как мне из этого массива uri вывести список маршрутов использующих метод GET и префикс admin?

Список маршрутов:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/','DashboardController@index')->name('admin.index');
        Route::get('/route', 'RouteController@index')->name('admin.route');
        Route::prefix('blog')->namespace('Blog')->group(function(){
            Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController', ['as' => 'admin']);
        });
        Route::prefix('admin-managment')->namespace('AdminManagment')->group(function(){
            Route::resource('/menu', 'MenuController', ['as' => 'admin']);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос конечно коряво, но получилось что хотел, а именно
контроллер

```
public function index(){
    $app = app();
    $routes= $app->routes->getRoutes();
    return view('admin.route', compact('routes'));
}
```

Шаблон Blade

```
<select name="routes" id="route">
    @foreach ($routes as $route) 
        @foreach ($route->methods as $item)
            @if (($item == 'GET') and(mb_substr($route->uri(), 0, 5) == 'admin'))
                <option value=""> {{ $route -> uri() }} </option>
            @endif
        @endforeach

    @endforeach

</select>
```

Comment: Изменил контроллер: public function index(){
  $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
  return view('admin.route', compact('routeCollection'));
 }